# Tomcat SSL-tracking-mode with nginx

Tags: tomcat, ssl, nginx, https

I want to use session-tracking by using the SSL tracking mode tomcat provides. The tomcat is located behind ether an apache server or an nginx server, communication via ssl to the client.

The problem is: As long the Tomcat is configured for SSL the nginx does not redirect to it.

The nginx server is currently configured this way.

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  localhost;

    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  key.pem;

    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
   location / {
                proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
       proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8443/;

    }

}
```

the Tomcat is configured as

```
    <Connector
       protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
       port="8443" maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>


    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"
       remoteIpHeader="x-forwarded-for"
       remoteIpProxiesHeader="x-forwarded-by"
       protocolHeader="x-forwarded-proto"/>
```

Therefore I have a few question:

Is it possible to use SSL-based tracking behind an http server?
Is there a special connector needed?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the AJP connector, and your frontend will then forward this information that you need (SSL session among others). For this you also need to change the proxypass of your frontend to use the ajp protocol.